# Record incoming Gmail messages in Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

**Hi people.**
I am just starting to learn GS.
I cannot understand why the data is not written to the Google sheets.
Everything is logged correctly.
I ran the script through a container, granted access.
And I need this script to only receive unread messages and mark them as read.

I would be very happy if you correct my script.

```
    function Gmail() {
 
    //this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheet2'); //gets the right sheet

    /* searches your GMail for emails matching things "label:unread" + " label:support"
    (support is the name of the folder into which letters are collected) */
    var query = "label:unread" + " label:support"; 

    var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

    var supportStats = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

        for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
            var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
            var to = messages[m].getTo(); //to field
            var time = messages[m].getDate(); //date field
            var subject = messages[m].getSubject(); //subject field
            var body = messages[m].getPlainBody(); //body field
            var mId = messages[m].getId(); //id field to create the link later
   
            if (query === "label:unread" + " label:support") {
               supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
            }
            messages[m].markRead(); // marks as read
        }
    }
 if(!threads.length) return; //  if there are no unread ones, do nothing
 sheet.getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,2,supportStats.
 length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- One of the main issues is that your code gets the html body which
  contains a large amount of text since it returns the html body of the message.
- However, if you still want to get the body, I would advice you to get the plain body instead. To achieve that you can use [getPlainBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getPlainBody()) which gives you the content of the body of this message without HTML formatting.
- Also you call `appendRow()` inside a for loop which is a very computationally expensive approach. Instead, I would recommend you to use [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

---

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {

//this is just the stuff that recognizes what spreadsheet you're in
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheets = ss.getSheets();
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data"); //gets the right sheet

//this chunk gets the date info  
 var today = new Date();
 var dd = today.getDate()-1;
 var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0 DO NOT FORGET THIS
 var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
 var yesterday = yyyy + '/' + mm + '/' + dd;

//****************************************************  
/*searches your GMail for emails matching two things, written after yesterday and with the label support*/
  var query = "label:unread after:" + yesterday + " label:support";

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);

  var supportStats = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();

    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {

      messages[m].markRead();
      var from = messages[m].getFrom(); //from field
      var to = messages[m].getTo();//to field
      var time = messages[m].getDate();//date field
      var subject = messages[m].getSubject();//subject field
      var body = messages[m].getPlainBody();//body field
      var mId = messages[m].getId();//id field to create the link later
      var mYear = time.getFullYear();
      var mMonth = time.getMonth()+1;
      var mDay = time.getDate();
      var messageDate = mYear + '/' + mMonth + '/' + mDay;

      if (messageDate === yesterday) {
      
      supportStats.push([from,to,time,subject,body,'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/'+mId])
      
      }
      
    }

  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow()+1,1,supportStats.length,supportStats[0].length).setValues(supportStats); //writes to the spreadsheet

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping.
Run your script, error here.
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRange' of null at myFunction (Code: 47: 9)

Comment: @АртурПетров I updated my answer. Please try again and let me know.

Comment: The only thing left is to filter out unread and put the mark as read. Tell me how to do this?

Comment: @АртурПетров I edited my answer. Now it considers the **unread** emails: `label:unread` and then it **reads** them if `messageDate === yesterday`. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @АртурПетров if you don't want to consider only unread emails then remove `label:unread` from the code.

Comment: Yes almost.
At the end, the script needs to mark "unread" as "read." (I just realized that in this scenario, checking against the date is unnecessary.)

Comment: @АртурПетров I edited my answer. You can put `messages[m].markRead();` outside of the if statement.

Comment: Marios.
Many thanks. You bring light to this world.
May good luck always be with you.

Comment: Hello, Mario.
I hope I don't bother you too much.
I changed the code a bit. The code is working. But sometimes there are problems due to data loss on Google servers >>> Messages in the mailbox are marked as "read", but they are not written to the table. Probably  need to write a log, and before as mark emails as  "read" , need to check that the data has been written to the sheet in the table.
Help please, I cannot find a solution for the second day.

Comment: @АртурПетров Unfortunately, stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Please post a new question regarding this issue and I will be very much happy to answer it.

Comment: Here's a new topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63952049/write-incoming-gmail-label-unread-label-name-to-google-sheet-with-valid